# Customizing Spyder for input values

Tags: python, spyder

In Spyder IDE when I use the "input" python function the prompt automatically remains on the editor while it waits for input, so in order to input the required value I have to move back to the console.

I do it quickly via the shortkey Shift + Ctrl + I but is there a way that makes the prompt automatically move to the console to provide the input?